# Typescript declare scoped runtime interface

Tags: typescript

I would like to declare a global interface which will be available in runtime under a specific name.

```js
/** My code which will be injected */

// import Vue from "vue"; <- with this we would have two vue instances

// ts-ignore <- Vue is only available in runtime
Vue.component();
```

```js
/** Code of vendor which I cannot modify */
(function () {

const Vue = *VUE CODE*
{{ transpiled-code-gets-injected-here-in-runtime }}

})();
```

In this example `Vue` is not available in any window or global context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// global.d.ts

declare type VueDeclaration = import('vue').default;
declare class Vue implements VueDeclaration{}
```

when we declare the `vue` type and use it as extends in a class, then we can use it as if it was in the context of the execution.